# R: read contents of text file as a query?

Tags: r

Using R, I just want to read the contents of a file into a variable like:

```
query <- read_file_contents('biglongquery.sql')
```

As to avoid putting, well, big long queries in the R script itself. I do *not* want to read in data like CSV (e.g. `read.tables`), etc- just the raw text.

Comment: I think `scan` can do this but I'm not sure (so not posting it as an answer)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to make a view of you `biglongquery`? You could then use the `RODBC` package to connect to your `SQL` database and call `select * from myShortView` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: I agree with Chase, views can be read just like tables, I think R does not even distinguish.

Comment: @Chase Under assumption that ones has privileges to create views on DB. And OP method don't change database structure (it is "read-only").

Comment: @ Marek - duly noted. I guess I tend to take my sys admin privileges for granted from time to time and can go Little Bobby Tables on any database I'm dumb enough to connect to: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Noting that it's 9 years since the last response on this, am using a table-valued function to store the query logic.  Tried a stored procedure - didn't work.  This is with SQL Server 2016 and RGui 3.5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scan does the job, but the function for this purpose is actually readLines().

```
query <- readLines("biglongquery.sql")
```

This gives you a vector with the lines. To combine them to one single variable, you can use the paste function, e.g.

```
one.variable <- paste(query,collapse="\n")
```

Comment: And if one use it a lot then `readQuery<-function(file) paste(readLines(file), collapse="\n")` could be useful.

Comment: Other than all the memory work on first splitting and recombining the lines in the file, this method has the disadvantage that any trailing newline will be lost.  Also, you have normalised the line terminator to \n.

Comment: @OliverBock That's correct. To my knowledge, there is no function that reads the content of an entire file and stores it as a single value. And R usually works with \n as line terminator, but you can use any one you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- paste(scan("foo.sql",what="",sep="\n",blank.lines.skip=FALSE),collapse="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a .R script with query definition

```
# content of biglongquery.R
query <- "
SELECT
    very_long_list_of_fields
FROM ...
"
```

and then use it in the main script using

```
source("biglongquery.R")
```